# to check if an Object is present in List in Drools

Tags: drools

I am newbie in Drools and given the work to write rule files i.e. drl files. I am facing one issue.

The operator `contains` is used to check whether a field that is a Collection or array contains the specified value.

Object( objList contains "bye" ) -- to verify if "bye' is there in objList or not i.e. for verifying String.

But, I have List of Objects and want to check if List contains any particular Object or not so I used the above replacing String with an object but that didn't work.'

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Try `memberOf` operator 
From Drools [Rule Language Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.M2/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html)

> The operator memberOf is used to check whether a field is a member of
>   a collection or array; that collection must be a variable.
>   Blockquote